Does the law protect some types of criminal?
Some kinds of crime - such as grooming children - leave no trace, and are difficult to prove. For some reason, police won't even investigate. People get away with these kinds of crimes, reoffend, and society suffers.
One thing protecting the criminals in situations like this is that in court, the jury will only hear about one person's trauma. With only one person telling their story, it's just "he says, she says". But in many cases, the offender has had multiple complaints made against them.
In the case of John Smyth, though, we now accept that his accusers were telling the truth. How could so many people be making up the same story? Here in New Zealand, the survivors of Lake Alice who described abuse to police and others were ignored at the time, but the combined weight of their voices is impossible to deny.
Does the legal system protect such people because of its insistence on isolating the alleged crime?
Edit
John Smyth was a British barrister who sadistically abused many children. He was never found guilty.
Cases such as his bear similarities to numerous less newsworthy cases: repeated, individually unprovable incidents. In some cases, the incidents are crimes. In others, they are not yet recognised as crimes: stalking, coercive control, grooming.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Some crimes are harder to prove than others
The law treats all crimes equally in that they must be proved beyond reasonable doubt. However, the nature of particular crimes means that this can be harder or easier to prove. For example, robbery is easier to prove than burglary because the former involves the thief coming face-to-face with the victim—who can then testify—while the latter usually has no witnesses.
Sex crimes are among the hardest to prove because these crimes usually only have two witnesses: the victim and the perpetrator. There is often a delay in reporting such crimes because of historical (and wrong) cultural norms that being a victim of such a crime is in some way shameful. Assuming the alleged perpetrator does not testify (as is their right and the norm), the jury can only decide whether they believe the victim or not.
All of this is just made worse when the victim is a child.
Each crime must be proved individually
As others have stated, this is a long-standing common law rule against tendency evidence unless "the court thinks that the evidence will, either by itself or having regard to other evidence adduced or to be adduced by the party seeking to adduce the evidence, have significant probative value."
At least in australia, the legislatures of states that have adopted the model Evidence Act accept that tendency evidence of a person accused of a child sexual offence about "the sexual interest the defendant has or had in children (even if the defendant has not acted on the interest)" or "the defendant acting on a sexual interest the defendant has or had in children" is of sufficient probative value to be admitted.
This should make it easier to convict serial offenders, all else being equal.
Police and prosecutors have limited resources
While there has been a long-standing bias against investigation or prosecuting crimes where the victim is a woman or a child, because of patriarchy, that has lessened in recent decades, although I do not believe that it has been totally eliminated.
However, the fact is that police and prosecutors have to decide which offences they will devote resources is still relevant for other reasons:

some crimes are easier to prove (see above). Police and prosecutors prefer to win rather than lose because they're people.
some crimes are more political. Murders, armed robberies, and crimes involving police pursuits hit the news and put pressure on police and prosecutors to 'solve' them. Individual child sexual grooming cases don't.
individual factors. Witnesses are not all created equal. One 4-year-old victim may be articulate, calm, consistent and able to present a very clear and compelling narrative of their experiences; another may be none of those things. There will be a greater incentive to prosecute a case involving the former child over the latter.

All of those reasons suck, and in an ideal world, every crime would be thoroughly investigated, and every alleged perpetrator would face their day in court. But we don't have that world; we're stuck with this one.

You are referring to the longstanding common law rule against "propensity" evidence. A person on trial is protected from having their character tarnished by introducing facts of unrelated wrongdoing. If this were allowed, the risk of prejudicial reasoning is high.
This rule applies no matter the crime being charged.
The rules of evidence do not categorize accused into "kinds of offenders." Each is presumed innocent of the charged offence until proven guilty.
The quotations that follow are from R. v. Handy, 2002 SCC 56.
Similar fact evidence or propensity evidence is generally inadmissible
There is a rule against the admission of "similar fact evidence" when used to establish the propensity of the accused to do certain things or to merely impugn the accused's character. Evidence which would only attempt to show that the accused "has the propensity or disposition to do the type of acts charged" is to be excluded.
This is a rule from at least as far back as the 17th century and the Supreme Court of Canada has said "[t]he exclusion of evidence of general propensity or disposition has been repeatedly affirmed in this Court and is not controversial."
"Its potential for prejudice, distraction and time consumption is very great and these disadvantages will almost always outweigh its probative value."
There is an exception to the exclusion when the probative value of the evidence is high enough
There is, however, an exception to the exclusion: this is where the "similar facts" become so much more focussed and specific to the circumstances similar to the charge that the probative value of the propensity evidence becomes more clear. The test for admissibility is as follows:

evidence of propensity, while generally inadmissible, may exceptionally be admitted where the probative value of the evidence in relation to an issue in question is so high that it displaces the heavy prejudice which will inevitably inure to the accused where evidence of prior immoral or illegal acts is presented to the jury.
...
Similar fact evidence is thus presumptively inadmissible. The onus is on the prosecution to satisfy the trial judge on a balance of probabilities that in the context of the particular case the probative value of the evidence in relation to a particular issue outweighs its potential prejudice and thereby justifies its reception.

For example, in Makin v. Attorney-General for New South Wales, [1894] A.C. 57 (P.C.), similar fact evidence was allowed to be admitted to show that there were dead babies buried in the backyard of the accused and at previous residences of the accused. The probative value of such coincidences was too high to warrant exclusion of the evidence.

I think what you're saying here is that yes, the way the law is applied does protect some kinds of offenders, and it's for this reason. Their loophole is in the "almost always" of the Canadian Supreme Court.

@OutstandingBill The law requires a certain standard of evidence which is meant to protect everyone, whether they are offenders or not. Trial is a delicate process for many reasons but one of the main ones is the ease with which a person, without meaning to, can become convinced of someone else's guilt for what is ultimately a spurious reason.

In the Smyth case specifically, the problems are that people in positions of authority who knew of his abuses of children essentially helped to cover them up, and the police did not investigate what did come to their attention until after the publication of a TV documentary about Smyth's abuses.
Then Smyth died during the police investigation, so he wasn't tried in court.
My point is that the law can't do anything by itself. We rely on people to report allegations, make complaints, 'chase' the police to make sure they're doing something; we rely on the police to take complaints seriously, not requiring outright belief from the police, but to take complaints seriously and investigate without fear or favour, and so on.

Cover-up (quoting the Makin review):

20.1 There is clear evidence that the abuse perpetrated by John Smyth in the UK were “covered up”, minimised and held as ‘secret’ from at least 1982 (and possibly earlier), and that this cover-up applied until later in the review period. The detailed chronological narrative and analysis of events details how this conclusion has been reached.


22.2.1 Over almost 40 years, this Review evidences the many Church officers and institutions that had knowledge to some extent, of the abuse. This includes clergy, individuals that became Clergy during the period of Review, lay people, members of General Synod, and spouses, or friends of Church officers. A criminal investigation into this abuse did not take place until 2017, when the abuse was made public knowledge by Channel 4. Police were notified of the abuse in conversation with a Church officer in 2013 but no crime was recorded. In 2014 and 2016, crimes were recorded, however no investigation followed and concerns about this were not escalated by Church officers. The Church did not carry out a risk assessment of John Smyth, nor instigate any internal investigation or thorough analysis of the case and the knowledge and role of Church officers, until this Review commenced. ...


Thank you for laying out those facts. As Dale M notes, the police like to win, and if they know they can't win, they won't try. The reason they can't is because the standard of proof required is too high for them to win. The law dictates that standard of proof. Therefore, the law protects people like Smyth.

@OutstandingBill I disagree.

@OutstandingBill facts are that people do go to prison for similar behavior. Your interpretation is driven by your personal anger, not a rational analysis. Maybe he'd be found guilty had he been put on trial, we'll never know. But in the end the law is an abstract - the actual enforcement is done by actual people. Sometimes those break the law themselves, police is not perfect.

@OutstandingBill Prosecutors have to only prosecute when they have a reasonable chance of winning. It costs much more money to make a prosecution than it does it to make a defence. Unfortunately, there is a value proposition that prosecutors have to make i.r.t whether the prosecution is worth the taxpayers money that the case will cost.

@littleadv, my interpretation is driven by awareness. That awareness does cause anger, but there is nothing irrational about the awareness. Please desist from telling me what I think. You'll note from Dale M's answer that in Australia, tendency "is of sufficient probative value to be admitted". So in some places, my views are "rational", while in others, they're not?
